# Integrating Geofire with existing firebase database

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, geofire

I have gone through the github Fish examples for [Geofire](https://github.com/firebase/geofire-js/tree/master/examples) but still unclear of how to implement it within my app.
 My use case: My app shows events/meetups to logged in users. Currently within my app I have firebase listener at a firebase ref(events).

```
database.ref('events').orderByChild('startTime').on('value', (snapshot) => { 
 const feed = snapshot.val() || {}
})
```

Currently, at the initial load, the client app fetches the entire object at the events ref and then each of the events data is displayed to the user in a table(each row an event).

I understand that with geofire I can use the set() function to save each event key along with its geolocation[lat, lng]. And then using query I can retrieve the list of the event keys that fall within the specified radius to users current location(html5 geolocation). But What do I do with the keys, since there is no data attached to them, do I set individual "on" listeners for each event key at the Events ref? and then display the events data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use Geofire, you end up with two branches in your JSON tree: one with the geodata for objects and one with the actual data.

```
objects
  objectId1: { ... }
  objectId2: { ... }
  objectId3: { ... }      
geodata
  objectId1: { ... }
  objectId2: { ... }
  objectId3: { ... }
```

When you fire a GeoQuery against the `geodata` node, you get back the keys of the objects that fall within the range of that query. So for example `objectId2` and `objectId3`.

You then use that key to look up the corresponding JSON object under `objects`. For example when using [`key_entered`](https://github.com/firebase/geofire-js/blob/master/docs/reference.md#geoqueryoneventtype-callback):

```
geoQuery.on("key_entered", function(key, location, distance) {
  console.log(key + " entered query at " + location + " (" + distance + " km from center)");
  ref.child("objects").child(key).once("value", function(snapshot) {
    console.log(snapshot.val());
  });
});
```

Comment: If new events keys are added to the geofire ref using(set()) after the above query is created on client app and if it falls within the radius would the "key_entered" query detect the addition and retrieve key? Also,the same question for event key being deleted, would the key_exited for the key trigger?

Comment: If new keys are associated with a location that is in range of an active GeoQuery, it will fire `key_entered`. If you're having problems making this work, share the [minimal code that reproduces the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).