# React native fetching GeoFire and only one data can display in flatlist

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native, geofirex

I am using react native and Geofire to create an app which it fetches the nearest location and display in FlatList. My code is base on [this stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40806524/integrating-geofire-with-existing-firebase-database) and I am not sure why I can't display the data.

My database structure: The data node contains the `data` and the `location` set by GeoFire. Apparently, they have the same key. 
[image]

I tried to `console.log` to see what happen in the code. It shows the data fetched 3 times in 3 arrays. 
[image]

It is my code firebase code: (I have tried different `radius` in order to see the result and it fetched expected result so it work fine, I also tried to use `once` instead of `on` but no luck)

```
export const useGeoFireDatabaseQuery = (coordinates) => {

  const [data, setData] = useState([])
  const geoQuery = geoFire.query({
    center: coordinates,
    radius: 2
  });

  useEffect(()=>{
    if (coordinates != null) {
    geoQuery.on("key_entered",  (key, location, distance)=> {
      firebase.database().ref('data').child(key).on('value', (snapshot) => {
     const dataList=[]
      snapshot.forEach(doc => {
        dataList.push(doc.val())
       })

         setData(dataList)
      })

    })
    }
    },[])
  console.log('Data',data)
  return data
}
```

**My problem is** firebase and geoFire run it 3 times so I could not get all the data together. It will only display the 'Last' setState data to flatlist. **How can I solve this issue?** 
Many Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Since you always create `dataList` as an empty array in the line `const dataList=[];`, the component forgets its old state every time it gets new data. Instead, you can copy the current `data` array into `dataList` before adding the new items:

```js
const dataList = [...data];
```

---

As a side note, the second argument of your `useEffect` hook is currently an empty array (`[]`). To keep your query fresh whenever `coordinates` changes, you should include `coordinates` in the array:

```js
useEffect(() => {
    // ...
},[coordinates]);
```